# Call JS method from Razor form submit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

When I submit the form I want to fire-up the `Javascript` method written below. This `JS` method will send a POST request to the backend. However, in the code written below this `JS` method is not being fired. Can someone please help me how to correct this ?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal",  onsubmit = "submitdata" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EMAIL, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email,  new {id ="Email", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.pwd, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.pwd, new {id="pwd", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" onsubmit="submitdata"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function submitdata() {
    var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/Account/Reg',
        data: {
            email: email,
            password: pwd
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#success__para').html("You data will be saved");
        }
    });

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss () in your onsubmit attribute;

```
onsubmit = "submitdata()"
```

Comment: Instead of using `onsumit = "submitdata()" ` on the form How can i use it on the button click ?

Answer (score 0):

As Vostrugin mentioned in his answer, you are missing `()` in the method call.

Here is the [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) way (using jQuery)

```
function submitdata() {
   // your existing code
}
$(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     submitData();
  });
});
```

If you want to wire it with a specific button click, use a jQuery selector to get the button and bind the click event.

```
<input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Register"/>
```

and

```
$(function(){
  $("#myButton").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     submitData();
  });
});
```

With this approach, you should remove the `onsubmit` event from your UI markup.